# react - how to instantiate a component and when are they identical?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, instance, lifecycle

I have some questions about the following code.

From what I understand, `Example` is a class, and it first got instantiated when it is passed as an argument in `ReactDOM.render`.

When it got rendered, it first called the `componentWillMount` method.

What I don't understand is the second `ReactDOM.render` call.

Is the `<Example />` in the second `ReactDom.render` call the same as the first one.

I thought the second call instantiate a second instance of Example, but apparently it didn't because the `componentWillMount` method didn't get called.

Why are the two `<Example />` the same instance? How can I create a second/separate instance of `<Example />`?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Example extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    alert('component is about to mount!');
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

setTimeout(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Usually, you only call ReactDOM.render once, this is probably an example to show that you can call ReactDOM.render multiple time to overwrite an existing mounted component

Comment: Moreover, as the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html) states : _If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React element._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two instances , then you should have two main divs with different IDs:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Example extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    alert('component is about to mount!');
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('appTwo')
);
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="appTwo"></div>
```